# Is it possible to redirect URL for GitHub pages?

Tags: http, url, redirect, github-pages

I set up a simple HTML page on GitHub pages with a custom domain.

I have another project that I'd like to connect with it but via subfolder.

Say, my GitHub project is `www.githubpagessite.com` and I'd like when users click on the link `www.githubpagessite.com/docs/getstarted` internally, they would be redirected to `docsproject.com/docs/getstarted` so that page would load into the browser, but they wouldn't see any changes in URL.

Probably it's called forwarding and I did it a long time ago for Asp.Net but don't know how it can be organized with GitHub pages (if even possible).

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: @Evert thanks, I suspected it but was not sure.